# Installation of texlive packages ubuntu 20.04

Tags: packages, texlive, installing, ubuntu, linux

I'm kindly asking for your help. I'm trying to install texlive on Ubuntu 20.04. I tried to find information on how to install it, but I found out there are several packages: texlive-full,texlive-latex-extra,texlive-science, texlive-latex-extra-doc, texlive-science-doc, etc. Furthermore, I want to know if I can install texlive-latex-extra and texlive-science, texlive-latex-extra-doc, texlive-science-doc or if texlive-latex-extra already includes texlive-science. Additionally, I also want to be aware of any potential conflicts that may arise when installing these types of packages. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: they are apt pakages for the debian-packaged texlive, they manage their own dependencies so nothing bad happens if you install overlapping collections, you do not get multiple copies. Unless you are really tight for disk space I'd simply install `texlive-full` and get it all

Comment: Hello, @DavidCarlisle, thanks for your response. This means I can install multiple collections without worrying about conflicts. Have a nice day.

Comment: As David says, it is usually easiest to just install `texlive-full`, because that gives you all available packages. You then don't have to worry about finding out which collection contains a package when you load a new one. The only thing to note about distribution-provided TeX Live (especially on Ubuntu LTS) is that they are usually not very up to date. That need not necessarily be bad, but if you need brand new packages or new features, keep in mind that the TeX live in Ubuntu 20.04 is over three years old now.

Comment: Hello, @moewe, thanks for your response. The texlive-full is at least about 4 GB, and it seems to include a lot of stuff (different languages, etc.) that won't be necessary for me. That's why I want to install smaller packages like texlive-science. You said that they are not up-to-date; may I ask where I can find up-to-date versions for Ubuntu 20.04 ?

Comment: If you don't have the space or time for a 4GB download, you can install only the collections you need, but of course that requires some research because you need to find the relevant collections for you. The Ubuntu-provided packages are frozen. If you want an up-to-date TeX Live you can install the vanilla version from TUG.org (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864). This will give you an updateable system, but it requires more manual work. For many intents and purposes a slightly older TeX Live is not too bad.

Comment: @moewe, thanks again for your help.Have a nice day.